# Getting address from adding a constant to register

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Okay. I had a task which looked like this: `%edx` register has a value of `0xe000` and `%ecx` register has a value of `0x200`. Write down an adress calculated from:

1. `0x10(%edx)`
2. `(%edx, %ecx)`
3. `(%edx, %ecx, 4)`
4. `0x8(,%ecx,2)`

I know that in the first example it should be `0x10+0xe000`, in the second adress it should be `0xe000+0x200` etc. But when I want to test myself using assembly program, it doesn't work (throws `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`:

```
.section .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d"
    .text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function

main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $0xe000, -4(%rbp)
    movl $0x200, -8(%rbp)
    movl -4(%rbp), %edx
    movl -8(%rbp), %ecx
    movl $.LC0, %edi
    movl 0x10(%edx), %esi
    movl $0, %eax
    call printf
    movl $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

This is for example nr 1. What am I doing wrong? (Manjaro 64 bit)

Comment: You are not printing the address, you are trying to print the value from memory, but since you don't have a valid pointer that faults. Use `leal 0x10(%edx), %esi` instead.

Comment: Jesus, `leax` stands for Load effective address x, I should've figured it out myself. Thank you!